# Can I use regular expression in contains method

Tags: java, regex, string

Here is my code

```
public class regMatch {

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        String s = "1";
        System.out.println(s.contains("/[0-9]/"));
    }
}
```

Its printing false;

I want to use regular expression in `contains` method.

How can I use it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: I want to check whether is their any digit present in string or not

Comment: why do you insist on using `contains` method only?

Comment: You're aware that the classes and methods are documented using javadoc, right? So why don't you checki it by yourself? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: +1 for you for your bravery Ha Ha

Comment: @Pratik: going to the javadoc and reading it is much faster than asking a question here. You didn't show any research effort, and that's why you deserve downvotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to use regular expression in contains method.
>
> How can I use it

you can **not** use regex in `contains` method

Answer (score 3):

You don't need (and shouldn't use) delimiters in a Java regex

And the `contains()` method doesn't support regexes. You need a regex object:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(s);
System.out.println(regexMatcher.find());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class to test for regex matches. However, if you are just testing for the presence of digits in the string, directly testing for this would be more efficient than using a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `matches()` with the regex `.*[0-9].*` to find if there is any digit:

```
System.out.println(s.matches(".*[0-9].*"));
```

(or for multiline strings, use the regex `(.|\\s)*[0-9](.|\\s)*` instead)

An alternative - if you are eager to use `contains()` is iterate all chars from 0 to 9, and check for each if the string contains it:

```
    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        flag |= s.contains("" + i);
     System.out.println(flag);
```

Comment: This fails on multiline strings.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Thanks for pointing that out. You can of course add `\\s` to the regex. See edit.

Comment: Yikes. Better prepend `(?s)` to the regex. Or, even better, don't use `matches()` at all but `matcher.find()` which I proposed in my solution.

Comment: To add to Tim Pietzcker's comment, `(?s)` turns on DOTALL mode, which makes `.` matches anything. `.` by default does not match new line.